# Evitar Get de Favicon em Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

Tenho uma aplicação cliente-servidor em Flask, e quando faço um get para o servidor, outro get é feito pedindo o favicon do endereço.

Queria saber se tem como não fazer automaticamente esse get do favicon.

Comment: Isto é o navegador que força baixar o favicon não tem como impedir a não ser configurando o navegador para que não baixe o favicon.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nem se colocar uma imagem *fake* em base 64 no `href` do favicon?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pode ser que funcione, mas o comportamento pode variar, felizmente esse segundo get creio que ocorra somente no chrome, não custa nada testar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelos meus testes aqui, aparentemente se você definir uma imagem *fake* para o favicon você evitará que o navegador faça a requisição padrão. Para fazer isso, seria algo como:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Pois assim, ao tentar carregar o favicon, o navegador irá identificar que os dados que precisa para carregar a imagem já estão presentes no HTML e omite a requisição.